# Server printing message to all users console

Tags: linux, bash

I have a new server and it keeps printing the below to the console for all users

```
Jan 19 10:25:28 Hostname¿<28>fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 112.101.174.112
```

Anybody any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen that before, it's probably from the Sytem log file.

You can pipe the message into a log (might be a different conf file for you).

```
#sudo vi /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

Finding the line

```
 *.emerg *
```

And changing it to

```
*.emerg /var/log/emerg.log
```

The initial * says 'Everybody gets emergency messages'.

Comment: Thanks a lot that has worked